# Magento registration returns 'Last name cannot be empty'

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to deploy Magento 1.9.2.1. I used the package from the official site.

But a strange thing happened to me. Among all the instances I deploy, it fails at any page that requires validation of a customer information (registration, etc.). It returns the error 'Last name cannot be empty'. But even stranger, there were 1 or 2 times of success before the errors. That is, the error only happens after I have created 1 or 2 accounts.

I found that the validation method is in the model, as:

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
}
```

So I added some lines before it.

```
$errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The first name cannot be empty.');
$errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__($this->getFirstName());
$errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__($this->getLastName());
$errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__($this->getEmail());
```

This time there are 5 errors displayed at the registration page. As expected, the first is `'The first name cannot be empty.'`. But the second and third are all empty. The fourth is the email address I typed in.

Here comes another problem. The validation of the first name comes before that of the last name. Were they all empty, how could the error message be only `'The last name cannot be empty.'`?

And more substantially, why can I register at the very beginning? What is the substantial problem?

**UPDATE**: If I comment the validation for the two names, there are no more errors. But the account created has its last name empty, while first name as I typed in.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this query,

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'
```

later clean cache

Comment: OK. But any comments on the cause? If I only want to ignore the names, I can just comment the lines in the model.

Comment: Is it a systematic bug of Magento?

Comment: its is normally the validation rule set in magento, check http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-model-with-custom-validation-rules/

Comment: please see my updates. I think there is some substantial abnormality.